# The energy levels crossover problem in Quantum Annealing

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, experimental-realization, optimization, adiabatic-model

How to avoid energy levels crossover in quantum annealing by Kibble-Zurek mechanism? Any detailed references?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please give details about why you are interested in this question. Also, what have you found so far in the research you did prior to asking this community of volunteers?